# how can i put php code inside js function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how i can put this code

`<?php echo "user"; ?>`

inside this function

```
$(function() {
    $('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
        interactive: true,
        content: 'Loading...',
        contentCloning: false,
        contentAsHTML: true,
        contentAsPHP: true,
        animation: 'fade',
        functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
            // we'll make this function asynchronous and allow the tooltip to go ahead and show the loading notification while fetching our data.
            continueTooltip();
            origin.tooltipster('content', 
            '<div class="hovercard"> \n\
            <div> \n\
            <div class="display-pic"> \n\
            <div class="cover-photo"> \n\
            <div class="display-pic-gradient"></div>\n\
            <img src="img/NY.jpg" style="width:370px;height:200px;"> </div>\n\
            <div class="profile-pic"><div class="pic"> \n\
            <span class="chat-img">\n\
            <a href="#"><img src="image/19068919.54b2108777ce0.png" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" style="width:98px;height:98px;"></a>\n\
            </span></div>\n\
            <div class="details"> <ul class="details-list"> \n\
            </div></div></div><div class="display-pic-gradient"></div>\n\
            <div class="title-container"> \n\
            <a href="#">Tamil Selvan</a> \n\
            <p class="other-info">   PUT PHP CODE HERE      </p></div>\n\
            <div class="info"><div class="info-inner"> <div class="interactions"> <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Add Friend</a> <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Add Friend</a> \n\
            <a href="#" class="btn">Follow</a> </div></div></div></div></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

i want to place the php code inside the content of this function but i don't know how someone can help me

Comment: Learn some http-basics first

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: php is server-side, js is client-side, how do you envision this working?

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing if your above function and php code both are in same file then by putting below code at the place of `PUT PHP CODE HERE`.

```
   <?php echo "user"; ?>
```

but if not in same file then only one option is make ajax call on server and return code in response and paste there.